# Cutting roots of a live oak tree

Tags: trees, roots

I have a live oak tree on my front lawn. Roots from the tree are beginning to spread on to my neighbor's lawn which seems to be a problem to them. The roots in question are approx. 8 to 10 ft. from the trunk and at this time are not too large.  Can I safely cut these roots without causing damage to the tree?

Comment: Welcome to the group!  It would be great if you can post pictures so that you get relevant answers

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @kevinsky that it could be a duplicate unless there is something quite different about your situation.

Comment: they can cut their roots if they want, and leave your roots alone. If a branch dies, chop it off.